# Adding extension methods on LinkedListNode<T>

Tags: c#, linked-list

I'm trying to create a simple way to have my linkedlist act like a circular linked list in C#.

I have this code, and it does not want to show up as an extension method. Any idea why?

```
static class CircularLinkedList
{
    public static LinkedListNode<object> NextOrFirst(this LinkedListNode<object> current)
    {
        if (current.Next == null)
            return current.List.First;
        return current.Next;
    }

    public static LinkedListNode<object> PreviousOrLast(this LinkedListNode<object> current)
    {
        if (current.Previous == null)
            return current.List.Last;
        return current.Previous;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me in the following application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedListNode<object> node = new LinkedListNode<object>("Hello World");
        node.NextOrFirst();
    }
}

static class CircularLinkedList
{
    public static LinkedListNode<object> NextOrFirst(this LinkedListNode<object> current)
    {
        if (current.Next == null)
            return current.List.First;
        return current.Next;
    }

    public static LinkedListNode<object> PreviousOrLast(this LinkedListNode<object> current)
    {
        if (current.Previous == null)
            return current.List.Last;
        return current.Previous;
    }
}
```

Make sure that you are instantiating your LinkedListNode with the proper generic type , as using any other type (i.e. string) will not work.  However, you can extend this to support any type of LinkedListNode by changing your code to the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedListNode<string> node = new LinkedListNode<string>("Hello World");
        node.NextOrFirst<string>();

        LinkedListNode<int> node2 = new LinkedListNode<int>(3);
        node2.NextOrFirst<int>();
    }
}

static class CircularLinkedList
{
    public static LinkedListNode<T> NextOrFirst<T>(this LinkedListNode<T> current)
    {
        if (current.Next == null)
            return current.List.First;
        return current.Next;
    }

    public static LinkedListNode<T> PreviousOrLast<T>(this LinkedListNode<T> current)
    {
        if (current.Previous == null)
            return current.List.Last;
        return current.Previous;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work and it will work for other types as well!

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure that you add namespace of this extension class to the code you are using
2. classes by default are internal, so mark class as public if you are using this extension method from another project.
3. It would be better to use `LInkedListNode<T>` instead of `LinkedListNode<object>`

code.

```
public static class CircularLinkedList
{
    public static LinkedListNode<T> NextOrFirst<T>(this LinkedListNode<T> current)
    {
        if (current.Next == null)
            return current.List.First;
        return current.Next;
    }

    public static LinkedListNode<T> PreviousOrLast<T>(this LinkedListNode<T> current)
    {
        if (current.Previous == null)
            return current.List.Last;
        return current.Previous;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify `public` with your class. Your class is internal and probably due to that you can't access the extension methods, if your extension class is in a different project.

```
public static class CircularLinkedList
{
.....
}
```

To access it later use it like:

```
LinkedListNode<object> obj = new LinkedListNode<object>(null);
obj.PreviousOrLast();
```